# How to read a file with two columns into a script so that each line read as two variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing, variable

I have a file that has two columns like such.

```
cat test.txt

100 2007
FFF 1993
7E7 1994
4BB 1995
```

I need to input each of the lines into a script, and have the two columns assigned as separate variables so I can run them through a different loop, and then move onto the next line.

I have a long list of files that I need to perform a find and replace function for each of the pairs. I am converting sets to year which I already have mapped out.

My script will look something like this.

```bsh
SET=$1
YEAR=$2

for i in `ls` ; do
sed -i "" 's/"$1"/"$2"/g' $i;
done
```

I cant figure out how to have the test.txt loop the script with the new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `read` to split the lines based on whitespace (which it looks like your file uses). Something like this:

```
while read set year; do
    DoStuffWith "$set" "$year"
done <test.txt
```

Other notes:

- Note that I used lowercase variable names in the above example. There are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and the safest way to avoid conflicts with them is to stick to lower- or mixed-case variables (unless you *want* the special meaning).
- [Don't iterate over the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), just use `for i in *; do`. And double-quote the reference to `$i` to avoid weird parsing in some cases.

  Except you don't need to do that, `sed` can iterate over files all by itself if you use `sed -i "" 'whatever' *`.
- In the `sed` command, it looks like you're trying to use variable substitutions and double-quotes inside single-quoted strings, and that doesn't work. If you don't want the double-quotes to be literally part of the search/replace strings, use this instead:

  ```
  sed -i "" "s/$set/$year/g" *
  ```

  If you do want literal double-quotes in the search and replace strings, escape them:

  ```
  sed -i "" "s/\"$set\"/\"$year\"/g" *
  ```
- It looks like you're planning to loop through the file, and for each line loop over every file replacing that one string. Why not have a single run do *all* the replacements? That is, rather than running `sed` with the command `s/100/2007/g`, and then again with `s/FFF/1993/g`, and then again... why not run it just once with the command `s/100/2007/g; s/FFF/1993/g; s/7E7/1994/g; ...`?

  You'd need to build the `sed` command in a loop, something like this:

  ```
  sedCommand=""
  while read set year; do
      sedCommand+="s/$set/$year/g; "
  done <test.txt

  sed -i "" "$sedCommand" *
  ```
- Finally, global replacements like this worry me. Are you sure that "100" doesn't occur in any file except those instances where it should be replaced by "2007"? Does that include the test.txt file?

  Do you have a backup of all of these files? You really should before turning something like this loose on anything you don't want to lose.

Comment: +1 ... a related approach that avoids the shell loop might be something like `xargs -L1 printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' < test.txt | sed -i "" -f- -- *`